# Calculating the width of a font on screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

--- CORRECTION: ---

I was using the correct method `NSString sizeWithAttributes` 
 It appears my mistake was using the wrong attributes with it. 
 FontDescriptor attributes have nothing to do with the size attributes used by this method.
I should have been using these attributes...
[Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Character_Attributes)

---

I'm targeting iOS 8.  I'm on a MacBook with OS X 10.10

I've looked at countless stack overflow questions asking this question, and haven't found a single one that actually works, so I'm not sure why they are getting thumbs up. I've tried both depreciated methods, and current methods. I've tried all kinds of combinations and permutations of attributes with `NSString sizeWithAttributes` and nothing.

How do I know it's not working?  Because when I use a pixel measuring tool, the width it returns isn't nearly the width actually rendered on screen.

Also, the width returned is exactly the same regardless of what font size I use.

Here's some code I'm calling my sizing method with...

```
NSString *theString = @"Whose Your Daddy?";

CGFloat theResult = [self widthOfText:theString usingFontSize:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:12]];
NSLog(@"12 size = %f",theResult);

CGFloat theResult2 = [self widthOfText:theString usingFontSize:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:18]];
NSLog(@"18 size = %f",theResult2);

CGFloat theResult3 = [self widthOfText:theString usingFontSize:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:24]];
NSLog(@"24 size = %f",theResult3);
```

and here's the method that's evaluating the code above.  I left in 2 commented out variants fo the many many variants I tried ...

```
-(CGFloat)widthOfText:(NSString *)string usingFontSize:(NSNumber *)fontSize
{
    // UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[fontSize floatValue]];
    // UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic" size:[fontSize floatValue]];
    NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = @{UIFontDescriptorFaceAttribute:@"HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic", UIFontDescriptorSizeAttribute:fontSize};

    CGSize stringSize = [string sizeWithAttributes:attributesDictionary];

    return stringSize.width;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my code which I use to calculate width of text, you just need to pass the text, font and maximum height supported as a parameter in the method and it will return you the perfect width value..

```
- (CGFloat)findWidthForText:(NSString *)text havingMaximumHeight:(CGFloat)heightValue andFont:(UIFont *)font {
    CGSize size = CGSizeZero;
    if (text) {
#ifdef __IPHONE_7_0
        CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, heightValue) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:font } context:nil];
        size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height + 1);
#else
        size = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, heightValue) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
#endif
    }
    return size.width;
}
```

Try this method.. It works for me.. :)

Comment: Your's does actually work, and after researching it more, turns out mine WOULD have worked, but I was using the wrong attributes.  I noted that error in my original post above.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *OptName_length = @" Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam";
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0]};
CGRect rect = [OptName_length boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(tableView.bounds.size.width-150.0, MAXFLOAT)
                                              options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           attributes:attributes
                                              context:nil];

CGSize requiredSize = rect.size;
return requiredSize.height +5.0f;
}
```

This is am used for tableview height you can also get width from this...
Change the `CGSizeMake(tableView.bounds.size.width-150.0, MAXFLOAT)` the value to your need.

**For Height** `CGSizeMake(LablTextConstantWidth_InView, MAXFLOAT)` // 50.0 some value

**For Width** `CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT,LablTextConstantHeight_InView)`